Databricks not recognizing different profiles in .databrickscfg
I have the below databrickscfg file
[DEFAULT]
host = https://adb-xxxxxxxx.10.azuredatabricks.net
token = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-10
cluster_id = xxx-xxxxxx-habcabcz
org_id = 111111111111111
port = 11001

[PROD_TESTING]
host = https://adb-xxxxxxxx.13.azuredatabricks.net
token = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-13
cluster_id = xxx-xxxxxx-habcabcd
org_id = 111111111111111
port = 11001

When i run my test-notebook.py, it always takes the DEFAULT profile.
sparkSession = DatabricksSession.builder.profile('PROD_FINTECH_TESTING').getOrCreate()
i have Databricks CLI v0.217.1
I tried to create a workspace and send in the builder, but this is also taking the DEFAULT configuration.
w = WorkspaceClient(profile='PROD_TESTING')
sparkSession = DatabricksSession.builder.sdkConfig(w.config).getOrCreate()



The issue you are facing is that your test notebook is always taking the DEFAULT profile, even though you are specifying a different profile in your code. One possible reason for this could be that the PROD_FINTECH_TESTING profile is not defined in your .databrickscfg file. Add a new profile to your .databrickscfg file.
